# Boot into specific Hangout with one person

Tags: boot, google-hangouts

I would like my tablet to boot up into the Google Hangouts app, and open the conversation with a specific person.

I'm able to open the Hangouts app easily with this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart&hl=en) (or one of the many like it), but I need to open the conversation and this leaves me at the list of people page.

Resources that haven't quite gotten me there:

[Similar question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3k5hk3/anyone_know_how_to_open_a_hangouts_conversation/)

[Similar discussion for the Tasker app](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/tasker/13675kxhb8/open-specific-hangouts-conversation)

[YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o49wpYoeV6U)

When I try to use AutoContacts and log the `%achangouturi` variable it doesn't work. Many people say they needed to enable contacts syncing in G+, but the menus have changed and it does not work. That's the most common issue. But it's not mine.

Using the [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) app I was able to finally log the URI for the contact, and therefore have a unique ID with which I can one day hopefully open a conversation.

The way I got it was by using "Pick Contact", setting the output variable to contactURI, and then using log to log `{contactUri}`.

However, I am not able to open the hangout chat yet.

Using Automate, I choose launch app and choose hangouts.

I've tried using:

- ACTION: android.intent.action.VIEW
- DATA: content://com.android.contacts/data/xxxx

  - as well as DATA: content://com.android.contacts/contacts.lookup/xxxx
- MIME TYPE: vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.googleplus.profile.comm

In the Reddit answer, I don't understand and can't find the options to set the flags he did in either Tasker or Automate:

FLAGS: FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP

I've also tried using and not using `com.google.android.talk - com.google.android.apps.babel.phone.BabelProfileActionActivity` in the activity field.

Comment: I don't think a premade kit of this nature exists.

Comment: If the conversation always stays at a particular position then you may have some success using [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput)

Comment: If someone explains how to use the app [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) to do what I've described, I will mark this as answered.

Comment: I also should say that [Touchless Chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.touchlesschat&hl=en) might solve the problem, but it's not compatible with my device.

Comment: @Firelord Autoinput isn't supported on my device.

Comment: AutoInput not supported? Are you using an Android below 4.3? Also, is your device rooted because in that case, you can simply use a shell command to pass the flag.

Comment: Give that he wrote he used the code, it is very likely he used a Java function. Here is an example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/lqlCpcLf-J4 and you can add Java functions task using Code -> Java Function.

Comment: The device is not rooted, and I can't update past 4.3 because it will break 4G. Asus hasn't pushed a patch and probably never will.

Comment: If a solution is offered using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) would you consider ? Asking so that I can attempt

Comment: @beeshyams Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using tasker. You are completely on the right track, instructions below.

### SQL to find contact ID

Find the unique contact ID from the contacts database (which it seems you have already done). In case you have the wrong ID you can check with the SQL instructions. I had a few issues with this given I was only entering the first name when looking for the contact, and for some reason it wasn't being found. Anyway, this SQL query should work on the file: /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db

You can use a SQL app/program, browse to that file, and enter the SQL query:

```
SELECT _id FROM data WHERE raw_contact_id LIKE (SELECT _id from raw_contacts WHERE display_name LIKE "Contact Name" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1) AND DATA4 LIKE "10" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or you can enter this command into the terminal provided you have sqlite3 on your specific device (often not included in production release devices):

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db 'SELECT _id FROM data WHERE raw_contact_id LIKE (SELECT _id from raw_contacts WHERE display_name LIKE "Contact Name" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1) AND DATA4 LIKE "10" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1' | sed s/\"//g
```

Just replace "Contact Name" and put the contact you want to open inside the quotes. The full contact name preferably.

### Unrooted phone

I was working on a solution for this, but app backup is explicitly disabled in the contacts app manifest. Try the solution below and let me know if it works. I wasn't able to test it without root.

Install Tasker and AutoContacts. AutoContacts is paid, but you can get a in the next 15 minutes after buying the full version if you just want to test it.

Setup a task in tasker, name it, then add a new action Plugin > AutoContacts > AutoContacts. Then in the configuration type in "Contact Name or Nickname" the name of the desired contact. Press the tick. Press the back button in Tasker to get back to the list of actions for that task (you will have 1 now). Add a new action Alert > Flash. Press the button on the right of "text" that looks like a label and select "Autocontacts: 01. Hangout Uri ... %achangouturi". Press back to go to the action list. Press back again to save the task. Go back into the task and run it. The ID that you need for the contact you want will be at the end of the string that flashes up and will usually be 5 digits long. Run the task again if you didn't catch it in time.

### Creating Tasker task

Once you have the ID copied down, you need to go into Tasker to create the task that will open hangouts to the conversation. You have the right idea to use an intent, it is just a little different from what you already have. In the new task create a new action "+" select System > Send Intent. Create the intent in the following format:

```
Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
Cat: None
Mime Type: Leave blank
Data: content://com.android.contacts/data/#####
Extras/package/class: Leave blank
Target: Activity
```

Where ##### is the contact ID you found earlier. Mine were all 5 digits long.

Now you should be able to use this task for whatever your heart desires. Give it a test by pressing the play button in the task in Tasker.

A quick note, I mainly use mine in conjunction with AutoVoice in order to open a message I just got sent. I found it very useful to be able to launch hangouts back to the main screen and actually found this quite difficult as the Tasker "kill app" wasn't completely restarting hangouts. I found the way to do this is create an action "Launch App" and select the "Always launch a new copy" checkbox. This will always open hangouts to the main threads list.

Most of this is from this [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tasker/50lszUsTKmc/wwhVUwLWyksJ). Good luck, let me know if you run into any troubles.

Comment: The same should work in automate. I would just try leaving Mime blank and formatting the rest as it is above.

Comment: None of the SQL apps I've used have access to that database/folders. I've tried using adb, but I don't have permission to pull. Is there a way to do this without root?

Comment: hmmm... I have root. I'm not sure if you can. give me one sec.

Comment: Have you tried using the ID you already have with my method?

Comment: I just used automate on my own phone and compared the ID I got back from your process to the ID I got using the db file and unfortunately it's not the same. The Automate ID was 4 digits (with quite a but of information before that) and the string in SQL has always been 5 digits for me.
I did note though, that the automate ID is actually the same as the contact ID in the raw_contacts table, but the ID hangouts needs is the ID from the data table.
In theory you could try many IDs and you may eventually get the one you want. Because after much research it doesn't seem possible to get it un-rooted

Comment: Aha, I may have it. See update to test it for yourself.

Comment: I just tested this in Automate. It works excellently. Just pick the activity and select hangouts. Set the action to view. In the data URI put the exact same as the tasker "data" one above `content://com.android.contacts/data/#####` and replace the hashes with the contact ID that can be found in the un-rooted instructions. Leave everything else as it is and run the flow.

Comment: I don't have access to the %achangoutsuri using AutoContacts. I talk about it in my question. The string `%achangoutsuri` is sent rather than a 5 digit number. The most common reason why is G+ contacts syncing is not set up. Look at the last item of this [faq](http://joaoapps.com/autocontacts/faq/). However, the settings for my tablet do not line up with what he suggests. There is no Google+ top level setting. The closest I can find is Google > Choose my account > Contacts. I think Google has rolled contacts syncing out of G+. Thanks for your help, but it isn't quite working.

Comment: Try looking in the accounts and sync settings. You should be able to tick google+ which should sync the contacts from there. It is quite a lot easier I think and more reliable to root and get access to the db, but if you really are unable to do that just make sure the contact you are searching in AutoContacts has the EXACT NAME of the contact in your contacts that has a G+ profile listed under their contact. They must be listed in your contacts with a G+ profile linking, and you must use that exact name, otherwise it will not show up in autocontacts.

Comment: The crucial piece was making sure the contact name and G+ name matched exactly! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: That's OK, I'm glad I could help resolve it.